# Remove tag "a" within a specific div

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to remove a tag "a" within a specific div.

How can I access to the tag?

```
<script>
    window.onload = function myFunction() { 
        var elem = document.getElementById("divname");
      var a_tag_elem = elem.getElementsByTagName("a");
      a_tag_elem.remove();    
} 
</script>
```

Comment: The issue is probably that getElementsByTagName('a') returns a list so you need to do [0] afterwards

Comment: Try this: `var div = document.getElementById("divname");
var a = div.querySelector("a");
div.removeChild(a);`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
a_tag_elem[0].remove();
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: I  assumed that "a_tag_elem " not null but  your  "a_tag_elem " array is empty.you could control this array.